# bytearray to image

Tags: apache-flex

I want to implement an itemRenderer for list that contains image and label. the data provider of the list is list of objects that I got from back-end:

```
public class Object {
private String label;

private byte[] content;
```

}

my item renderer:

```
<s:MXDataGridItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                      xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                      xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">
<s:layout>
    <s:HorizontalLayout/>
</s:layout>
<mx:Image source="{data.content}"/>
<s:Label text="{data.label}"/>
```

I only got a broken image. did any body know why and how should I solve this problem.
thanks in advance
Yayo

Comment: What does `broken image` mean?

Comment: it's look like there is an image but you can't see the image

Comment: @user628213 share the screenshot?

Comment: unfortunately, I can't/don't allowed to post a screenshot :(, becasue I'm a new user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/Image.html#source

- A Bitmap or BitmapData instance.
- A class representing a subclass of
  DisplayObject.
- The BitmapFill instantiates the class and creates a
  bitmap rendering of it. An instance of a DisplayObject. The
  BitmapFill copies it into a Bitmap for filling.
- The name of an external image file.

spark.components.Image can not use ByteArray instance as source.
So you need to convert it to Bitmap instance.

Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<s:MXDataGridItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">

    <fx:Script><![CDATA[
        private var _bytesLoader:Loader;

        override public function set data(value:Object):void
        {
            super.data = value;

            _loadBytes(data.bytes as ByteArray);
        }

        private function _loadBytes(bytes:ByteArray):void
        {
            _destroyBytesLoader();

            if (!bytes)
            {
                return;
            }

            _createBytesLoader();
            try
            {
                _bytesLoader.loadBytes(bytes);
            }
            catch (e:*)
            {
                _destroyBytesLoader();
            }
        }

        private function _createBytesLoader():void
        {
            _bytesLoader = new Loader();
            _bytesLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, _bytesLoader_completeHandler);
            _bytesLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, _bytesLoader_errorHandler);
            _bytesLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(AsyncErrorEvent.ASYNC_ERROR, _bytesLoader_errorHandler);
        }

        private function _destroyBytesLoader():void
        {
            if (!_bytesLoader)
            {
                return;
            }

            _bytesLoader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, _bytesLoader_completeHandler);
            _bytesLoader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, _bytesLoader_errorHandler);
            _bytesLoader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(AsyncErrorEvent.ASYNC_ERROR, _bytesLoader_errorHandler);

            try
            {
                _bytesLoader.unload();
            }
            catch (e:*){}

            _bytesLoader = null;
        }

        private function _bytesLoader_completeHandler(event:Event):void
        {
            try
            {
                myImage.source = Bitmap(_bytesLoader.content).bitmapData.clone();
            }
            catch (e:*)
            {
            }
            _destroyBytesLoader();
        }

        private function _bytesLoader_errorHandler(event:Event):void
        {
            _destroyBytesLoader();
        }

        ]]></fx:Script>

    <s:layout>
        <s:HorizontalLayout />
    </s:layout>

    <s:Image id="myImage"/>
    <s:Label text="{data.label}" />

</s:MXDataGridItemRenderer>
```

Comment: thank u for the help. I found the problem. It was in database. It wasn't the correct bytearray. It works with only myImage.source = data.content